# How can I convert a MKV to MP4 using FFmpeg and hardsub the subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the following command :

```
ffmpeg -i old_video.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s mov_text new_video.mp4
```

It does convert the mkv to mp4, but the resulting mp4 doesn't have the subtitles hardcoded but as a separate channel, which is a problem as my TV doesn't support subtitles (but they show in a media player with subtitles support).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i old_video.mkv -vf subtitles=old_video.mkv -acodec copy new_video.mp4
```